# Determine if an org heading has children

Tags: org-mode

In elisp, how can I tell whether the org heading under point is a leaf node or whether it has child headings? I've found `org-list-has-child-p`, but I'm having trouble delivering the struct to the function.

Comment: the `outline-level` function may be of use: `(< (funcall outline-level) (save-excursion (outline-next-heading) (funcall outline-level)))`.

Answer (score 4):

You could try `org-goto-first-child` (inside `save-excursion`, so you don't actually move the point) and see if it returned `nil`:

```
(defun my-org-has-child-p ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-goto-first-child)))
```